# Apache Drill Compile Error when trying to use lag in a query

Tags: sql, lag, apache-drill

I'm trying to write a query using lag:

```
 select ID, NO_ITEMS_SOLD, CARD_KEY, 
 lag(CARD_KEY,1) over (order by ID, NO_ITEMS_SOLD) as prev_qtysold 
 from MACHINE_SPIN_LEVEL_CG order by ID, NO_ITEMS_SOLD;
```

And am getting this error whenever I run it:

> Query Failed: An Error Occurred
>       org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: CompileException: Line 218, Column 40: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "int, int, int, io.netty.buffer.DrillBuf"; candidates are: "public void org.apache.drill.exec.vector.NullableVarCharVector$Mutator.setSafe(int, java.nio.ByteBuffer, int, int)", "public void org.apache.drill.exec.vector.NullableVarCharVector$Mutator.setSafe(int, org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.NullableVarCharHolder)", "public void org.apache.drill.exec.vector.NullableVarCharVector$Mutator.setSafe(int, byte[], int, int)", "public void org.apache.drill.exec.vector.NullableVarCharVector$Mutator.setSafe(int, org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.VarCharHolder)", "public void org.apache.drill.exec.vector.NullableVarCharVector$Mutator.setSafe(int, int, int, int, io.netty.buffer.DrillBuf)" Fragment 3:0 [Error Id: 25810a7e-08f4-4818-a1cc-ef9a04f27a42 on jvullo-bb:31010]

Comment: please share sample data on which u ran this query. Also mention drill-version